# Hibernate criteria query to match against all child collection elements

Tags: java, hibernate

This question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888445/hibernate-criteria-restriction-on-a-property-for-all-elements-of-a-set) but the responses were minimal to that question.

I have a parent class with a Set of child entities. The child entities are just a wrapper for a string and live in a different table to the parent entity. I want to have a criteria query that returns the parent entities when all the members of the set of child entities return true to a condition. This condition is matching against one of a list of strings. Here's where I am:

```
Criteria c = criteria();
Criteria ands = c.createCriteria("ands");
Disjunction dis = Restrictions.disjunction();
for (String value : values) {
    dis.add(Restrictions.like("value", "%" + value + "%"));
}
ands.add(dis);
return list(c);
```

"ands" is the set of entities with a "value" field that is a string.
"criteria()" creates a criteria for the parent class. "list()" just calls criteria.list();

This is just matching against any of the elements, rather than all.

Hope this makes sense. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

As a theoretical exercise, you can do something like this:

```
Criterion condition = ...;

Criteria c = s.createCriteria(Parent.class, "p");
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Parent.class, "p2")
    .createCriteria("ands", "c")
    .add(Restrictions.not(condition))
    .add(Property.forName("p.id").eqProperty("p2.id"))
    .setProjection(Projections.id());

c.add(Subqueries.notExists(dc));
```

However, this approach is not good for practical use because it requires extra `join` (due to absence of `in elements` clause in Criteria API). Also note that it uses double negation (`SELECT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ... WHERE NOT <condition>)`), so it can have problems with `NULL`s.

**EDIT:** In HQL it can be written like this:

```
from Parent p
where not exists (select c from p.ands c where not <condition>)
```

or

```
from Parent p
where not exists (select c from Child c 
    where not <condition> and c in elements(p.ands))
```

But, as far as I understand, both queries can't be expressed in Criteria API (you can't write `from p.ands` in subquery and can't use `in elements`). So, in Criteria API you have to use additional join (note 2 `Parent`s):

```
from Parent p
where not exists (select c from Parent p2 join p2.ands c 
    where not <condition> and p = p2)
```

Comment: thanks for this. Just exploring its possibilities. Perhaps HQL would be better here, but I'm having trouble understanding the elements() clause. Could I use all elements(parent.ands) somehow perhaps?

Comment: ah - cool. This works as expected. Thanks very much. Just concerned about performance now.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that disjunction be a conjunction?

Comment: Hi,

It needs to be a disjunction because I want to select the parent where every element in the collection is like either string a, or string b, or string c. etc.